# Get location information in xamarin.forms by F #

Tags: android, f#

1. Now I'm thinking of making an app for android and want to get location information.
2. So I decided to use xamarin's android sdk.
3. But I want to use string as a parameter of unit, but I'm not sure if this is impossible or possible

```
open System
open Android.App
open Android.Content
open Android.OS
open Android.Runtime
open Android.Views
open Android.Widget
open Android.Locations

type Resources = syutoku.Resource

[<Activity (Label = "syutoku", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")>]
type MainActivity () =
    inherit Activity ()
    let L  = ""
    let mutable count:int = 1
    let location =  new Android.Locations.Location(L)
    let lL = [L]
    let soko =  lL.[0]
    override this.OnCreate (bundle) =

        base.OnCreate (bundle)

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        this.SetContentView (Resources.Layout.Main)

        // Get our button from the layout resource, and attach an event to it
        let button = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resources.Id.myButton)
        button.Click.Add (fun args -> 
            button.Text <- sprintf "%d clicks!" count
            count <- count + 1
        )
        let button_3 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resources.Id.myButton3)
        button_3.Click.Add (fun args -> 
            button_3.Text <- printfn "%s" soko
        )
```

I get the error FS0001 here.　↑

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `sprintf` instead of `printfn`, just like in the previous handler:

```
button_3.Text <- sprintf "%s" soko
```

Which, since `soko` is a string, could be simplified to:

```
button_3.Text <- soko
```

Comment: Thanks you. Apparently the debug was successful.